# Solve the linear system $Ax=b$ given $x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}$ and $b$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $x_{1}=(1,1,1)$ and $x_{2}=(0,1,1)$ and $x_{3}=(0,0,1)$, solve $Ax = b$ when $b=(3,5,8)$. Furthermore, what is A?

My thought process was as follows:

If $Ax_{1}=b$, then $A = (1,\frac{5}{3},\frac{8}{3})$

If $Ax_{2}=b$, then $A = (\frac{3}{2}, \frac{7}{2}, 4)$

If $Ax_{3}=b$, then $A = (3, 5, 8)$

Are these correct? Is it right for me to obtain these fractions when solving for A?

Comment: First of all, $A$ is a matrix. And you have to satisfy all three equations at once.

Comment: Are you solving for $A$?

Comment: From $x_3$ we know that the third column of $A$ must be $(3,5,8)^T$.  As $Ax_2$ is the sum of the second and third column of $A$, what must the second column be ...?

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is a matrix and $x_{1},x_{2}, x_{3}$ are Coefficients vectors and $b$ is the solution vector. You need to build a matrix: 
$$ \left[
      \begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1&0&0&3\\
        1&1&0&5\\
        1&1&1&8
      \end{array}
    \right]$$
    and then you can see:
 $L_{1} \Rightarrow x_{1}=3$ , 
$L_{2} \Rightarrow 3+x_{2} = 5\Rightarrow x_{2}=2$
    
$L_{3}\Rightarrow 3+2+x_{3}=8\Rightarrow x_{3}=3$